# Azure Stream Analytics Job delayed output of not matching records by 1 minutes between two event hubs

Tags: sql, azure-blob-storage, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

Could anyone help me, why the not matching records are delayed by exactly 1 minutes but the matching records are writing into blog storage container immediately.

Is there any way to avoid the delay even though eventA its not matching with other eventB (being my downstream system will take care in my use-case)

```
select b.eventenqueuedutctime as btime,a.Id,a.SysTime,a.UTCTime
,b.Id as BId,b.SysTime as BSysTime 
into outputStorage -- to blob storage (container)
from eventA a TIMESTAMP BY eventenqueuedutctime
left outer join eventB b TIMESTAMP BY eventenqueuedutctime
on a.id = b.id
and datediff(minute,b,a) between 0 and 180 -- join with last 3 hours of eventB data
```

Below is the output but look at the last row (Id:99) currentTime:T19:**42:13.1690000**Z which delayed by 1 minute compared top 4 rows (currentTime:T19:**41:13.1690000**Z)

FYI, Sending all the eventA Id (2,4,1,101,99) at once via EventDataBatch via Json serialization

```
{"btime":"2020-11-03T17:00:50.6360000Z","Id":2,"SysTime":"2020-11-03T11:41:12.860466-08:00","UTCTime":"2020-11-03T19:41:12.8604646Z","BId":2,"BSysTime":"2020-11-03T09:00:49.6751336-08:00","fullname":"cc","currentTime":"2020-11-03T19:41:13.1690000Z"}
{"btime":"2020-11-03T17:00:50.6360000Z","Id":4,"SysTime":"2020-11-03T11:41:12.8605138-08:00","UTCTime":"2020-11-03T19:41:12.8605135Z","BId":4,"BSysTime":"2020-11-03T09:00:49.6751371-08:00","fullname":null,"currentTime":"2020-11-03T19:41:13.1690000Z"}
{"btime":"2020-11-03T17:00:50.6360000Z","Id":1,"SysTime":"2020-11-03T11:41:12.8605561-08:00","UTCTime":"2020-11-03T19:41:12.8605559Z","BId":1,"BSysTime":"2020-11-03T09:00:49.6749841-08:00","fullname":"test","currentTime":"2020-11-03T19:41:13.1690000Z"}
{"btime":"2020-11-03T19:39:04.0100000Z","Id":101,"SysTime":"2020-11-03T11:41:12.860598-08:00","UTCTime":"2020-11-03T19:41:12.8605978Z","BId":101,"BSysTime":"2020-11-03T11:39:03.7462454-08:00","fullname":"test-101","currentTime":"2020-11-03T19:41:13.1690000Z"}
{"btime":null,"Id":99,"SysTime":"2020-11-03T11:41:12.860322-08:00","UTCTime":"2020-11-03T19:41:12.8602803Z","BId":null,"BSysTime":null,"fullname":null,"currentTime":"2020-11-03T19:42:13.1690000Z"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you use JOIN with DATEDIFF.

> The use of temporal joins, such as JOIN with DATEDIFF:
>
> Matches generate as soon as both sides of the matched events arrive.
>
> Data that lacks a match, like LEFT OUTER JOIN, is generated at the end
> of the DATEDIFF window, for each event on the left side.

More details, you can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-troubleshoot-output#the-first-output-is-delayed.

Comment: Could you clarify me in my case what the end of DATEDIFF window

Comment: Could you clarify me in my case ("datediff(minute,b,a) between 0 and 180") what the end of DATEDIFF window (How it is 1 minute)? To make it faster can i use datediff(second,b,a) between 0 and 10800 (meanwhile i will check by changing in seconds)

Comment: Now its working "dateDiff(second,b,a) between 0 and 10800" - End of the Window is 1 Sec, so the datepart plays a vital role to decide the end of the DATEDIFF window.